# Multi-tenancy support: Umbraco vs Orchard Project

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, orchardcms, multi-tenant

I am currently using an older version of Umbraco (4.03) and I have several basic sites (mostly 1 pagers) running under the same IIS Application.

I have a shared hosting account with Winhost.com, which doesn't offer multiple site application roots, just domain pointers, so I'm limited to a single CMS installation that supports multi-tenancy.

The Umbraco multi-tenancy setup is a bit hacky and I really need to upgrade. It seems that Orchard is more focused on multi-tenancy support. My Umbraco installation has some issues with shared skins, which has always been a little annoying.

So, the basic question:

Just based on the multi-tenancy scenario, has anyone had experience of both Umbraco and Orchard that can give me an opinion / comparison? If so, is the new version of Umbraco any better than the version i am using with regards to its multi-site support?

P.S. I'm aware there are a few questions on SO already concerning comparisons between the two CMS projects but I am specifically interested in a multi-tenancy comparison.

Comment: Please let us know your findings as I am really interested in this as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me start by saying that Orchard is a brilliant CMS, from what I've seen of it so far I prefer it to Umbraco.

But one word of warning, I had problems running a very small Orchard site on cheap shared hosting (in fact I was also using winhost) because of app pool memory limits. Orchard is quite memory hungry and in my case would jump to around 100mb of memory within a few page views. Most shared hosting packages limit the app pool to 100mb so [in my case](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/265462) it was recycling the app pool on every other page view. See [this thread](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/274603) as an example. I ended up using Umbraco instead.

Sorry, I know this is a bit off topic and doesn't answer the multi-tenancy question. But test for this early on in development.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Umbraco has essentially the same multi-tenancy setup as it had in 4.03.  You can assign a domain to any content item directly under the "Content" folder in the Content section of the admin.

I have done a few multi-site setups with Umbraco and I can understand how the skinning piece gets interesting fast.  We have used a CSS based solution to the skinning issue (select CSS files at the root).  That seemed better than a whole different set of Templates for each site.

Any thoughts on how you would like it to work?  Could be a good package in there somewhere.

Sorry, I can't answer the Orchard piece as I haven't used it and only have cursory knowledge of it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up that the current Umbraco multi-tenancy setup is still the same (fiddly). I need to spend some time with Orchard to test the multi-tenancy out in that.