# are there any multitenant cms based on .net

Tags: .net, content-management-system, multi-tenant

Can you recommend me any multitenant CMS? I am looking for the following features:

1. One different site per tenant
2. Each tenant must have its own independent database
3. Different authentication methods
4. Be able to create custom forms with custom fields, I know a CMS is a content management system, but we want to use a CMS as a starting point for custom applications, where I can add orders, invoices, etc, but I dont want to build that from scratch.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677694/multi-tenancy-support-umbraco-vs-orchard-project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) is a CMS built on top of ASP.NET MVC, and has a [multi-tenancy module](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-multi-tenant-orchard-site).  This allows for using a different databases per tenant.

It is extensible by [developing your own modules](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules).